# How to determine the sum for a table row?

Tags: sql

#### Given

I have two tables similar to following example:

`Table1`

| ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | ID4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| first | second | third | fourth |
| fifth | sixth | seventh | eighth |

`Table2`

| ID | Sum |
| --- | --- |
| first | 1 |
| third | 5 |
| fourth | 4 |
| fifth | 1 |
| seventh | 5 |
| second | 4 |
| eighth | 1 |
| sixth | 2 |

#### Expected

I need to get the total sum for each row of `Table1` based on the sum of the values from `Table2`.

For example, the first row of `Table1` becomes added the sum 14.
Because `first` (1) + `second` (4) + `third` (5) + `fourth` (4) = `14`

Resulting table:

| ID1 | ID2 | ID3 | ID4 | Sum |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| first | second | third | fourth | 14 |
| fifth | sixth | seventh | eighth | 9 |

How can I get the sum for each of those table rows by SQL ?

Comment: And please include your current query and explain why it's not working

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Join to Table2 four separate times:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2_1.Sum + t2_2.Sum + t2_3.Sum + t2_4.Sum As Sum
FROM Table1 t1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2_1 ON t2_1.ID = t1.ID1
INNER JOIN Table2 t2_2 ON t2_2.ID = t1.ID2
INNER JOIN Table2 t2_3 ON t2_3.ID = t1.ID3
INNER JOIN Table2 t2_4 ON t2_4.ID = t1.ID4
```

Answer (score 0):

You could join `Table2` with the condition being that `ID` is in one of the `Table1` IDs. Then using `group by` and `sum` get your desired output:

```
SELECT t1.*, SUM(t2.Sum) AS Sum 
FROM Table1 t1 
JOIN Table2 t2 ON
    t2.ID IN (t1.ID1, t1.ID2, t1.ID3, t1.ID4) 
GROUP BY t1.ID1, t1.ID2, t1.ID3, t1.ID4;
```